# Which SQLite.net PCL to use?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am very confused about how best to set up and application that will use SQLite and run on IOS or Android.  When I look on nuget I see there are two packages:

```
nuget package 1.2.0 by Krueger
nuget package 3.1.1 by Krueger and others
```

Can someone help by telling me what the differences are with these.

Also I tried to run with the 3.1.1 package (which also downloaded SQL.Net-core.PCL  I added using SQLite.net but I still get some errors such as:

```
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull] Type or namespace cannot be found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you using the one by Frank Krueger by the name [SQLite-net PCL on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/). There is another package by Oystein Krog et al. However, that package won't work with Android N, since it hasn't been update for a long time.

The one linked to, solves this problem and works very well on most platforms, event back to old systems such as iOS 6.